# Automatically create scheduled reminders for recurring events?

Tags: civievent

I modified an event template to include a scheduled reminder, but when I repeat the event (using the new recurring events feature), the scheduled reminder does not carry over.

Is it possible to create recurring events and all of them have the same scheduled reminder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phase1 of "recurring events" didn't include cloning scheduled reminders, probably because scheduled reminder (repeat tab) itself was being used for generating the recurring set. However both of them are different and there is no reason why scheduled reminder tab can't be cloned in the recurring set. Its just that no one explored them in phase1. Just added it to -  [phase2 wiki doc](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Recurring+Events%3A+Implementation+Plan).

The workaround for you is using "Administer>>Communications>>Scheduled Reminders" screen, to make a new reminder based on "Event Name" assuming all of events in your recurring set have same title. Otherwise you could base them on some "Event Type" meant only for that recurring set.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than create a scheduled reminder based on "Event Name", create it instead on "Event Type".  If you don't want to apply scheduled reminders to all events of this type, create a second type with a very similar name to use with events you want a scheduled reminder on - then attach scheduled reminders to only that event.

I can also see in the API explorer that there's a "cascade type", which seems to suggest that perhaps you could change the default cascade type to cause scheduled reminders to be cloned as well.  I'll let someone else speak to the feasibility of that.